# Combine similar rows in a SQL Alchemy query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm using sqlalchemy + postgresql.

Table

```
id type value
1  A    zacian
2  B    rayquaza
3  B    deoxys
4  A    solgaleo
5  A    mew
```

Expected Query Result

```
id type value
1  A    zacian, solgaleo, mew
2  B    rayquaza, deoxys
```

Basically i want the query to merge all rows having the same type into row and return the new list of rows.

I tried combining *distinct* and *group by* but I'm not experienced enough in this to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string_agg` in postgreSQL

```
select
    min(id) as id,
    type,
    string_agg(value, ', ' order by id) as value
from myTable
group by
    type
order by
    id
```

Output:

```
| id  | type | value                 |
| --- | ---- | --------------------- |
| 1   | A    | zacian, solgaleo, mew |
| 2   | B    | rayquaza, deoxys      |
```

if you want to give new values to id then use `row_number() over (order by type)` instead of `min(id)`

Comment: Thanks, took me a while to convert this to sqlalchemy but its worked.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to care about the ordering of the values.  If so:

```
select row_number() over (order by type) as id,
       type,
       string_agg(value, ', ' order by id) as value
from t
group by type;
```

You are accessing this from an application.  Even so, arrays are often more useful and strings.  So you might consider using `array_agg()` instead.